# What is the most basic line detection method in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, line, detection, vision

I'm just learning OpenCV, and have a question about line detection. I have a situation where I need to detect a horizontal black line on a white background. I am guaranteed that the line will always show up horizontally (within a few degrees) and need to detect where it is in the images from the camera.

My thought is, since it is always horizontal, I can just search vertically for the "edge" through a few columns on the image, and call it good. Maybe even narrow the amount of pixels I'm capturing from the camera as an extra boost in speed.

Is there a builtin function for this type of line detection though?

I don't need the extra power, and cannot afford the processing time of Canny or Hough, I just want to find a guaranteed horizontal line as fast as possible.

The images (with my solution running) look like this:

[image: Left is thresholded image, right is solution running. Green bars are horizontal edges, red mark the tape strips I'm interested in tracking.]

Comment: If I understand you right I've implemented something similar in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675509/finding-the-fitline-of-contours-in-opencv/21677214#21677214

Comment: Can you please show a few images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I ended up going with is a for loop. After thresholding the image, I search along two columns to find all the "edges" or changes in value. Then I process this list to find only horizontal pairs of edges.

I then find all lines that are close enough together, and have a desired infill (boolean comparison against thresholded image), which effectively only finds the strips of tape I am interested in tracking.

This takes about 1/50th the time of JUST the Canny call, not including the findContours, etc that are also necessary. I have not tested against Hough however, but I believe this will still be significantly faster.

Since the biggest issue was processing speed, I made several other optimizations as well.

Code can be found here (It's very well commented, I promise): [Code as a gist](https://gist.github.com/DweebsUnited/8d86ce7bc4750b168785e98c84ed5a93)

Comment: maybe you should make yourself familiar with Hough transform. Then you don't have to think about even considering it :)

Comment: Piglet, I'm familiar with it now, but again, since processing speed is an issue I need a simpler solution. I don't want to do "Edge Detection -> Hough Transform -> de-Houghing", when I can basically hack a custom edge detector together, that tells me where horizontal lines are. Again, I'm sure Hough works, but for this application, it is overpowered, and too slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the type of image you talking about then suggesting solution will be better.

Also I wonder, why you can't use Canny Detector which is not so computationally expensive. Further more you can downside your image, compute the edges and filter horizontal edges.

On the other hand, knowing that your horizontal edges are always horizontal on the image plane, you can use Template matching.